# Convert Curve path to straight path using jquery with animation

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg, svg-animate, tween.js

i am trying something to make straight path using curve path.
here i have 2 groups of paths when i click on route at that time clicked path animation with straight line and other line will be hide.

Hope that are you getting me what i want to create i have tried to many thing on it but not getting any idea

need your help

Thanks is advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   d3.selectAll('g#Route path').attr('stroke-width', '3');
  });
  
  d3.selectAll('g#Route').on("mouseover", function(e) {
   $(this).find('path').attr('stroke-width', '6');
  }).on("mouseout", function(e) {
   $(this).find('path').attr('stroke-width', '3');
  }).on("click", function(e){
   var totalWidth = 0;
   $(this).find('path').each(function(index){
    var getWidth = this.getTotalLength() / 2 ;
    
    //if(index == 0){
    // d3.select('svg#Layer_2').append('circle').attr('cx', '0').attr('cy', '10').attr('r', 5).attr('fill', '#000');
    // d3.select('svg#Layer_2').append('line').attr('x1', '0').attr('y1', '10').attr('x2', getWidth + totalWidth).attr('y2', '10').attr('stroke', '#333').attr('stroke-width', '2');
    // d3.select('svg#Layer_2').append('circle').attr('cx', getWidth + totalWidth).attr('cy', '10').attr('r', 5).attr('fill', '#000');
    //}else{
    // d3.select('svg#Layer_2').append('line').attr('x1', totalWidth).attr('y1', '10').attr('x2', getWidth + totalWidth).attr('y2', '10').attr('stroke', '#333').attr('stroke-width', '2');
    // d3.select('svg#Layer_2').append('circle').attr('cx', getWidth + totalWidth).attr('cy', '10').attr('r', 5).attr('fill', '#000');
    //}
    totalWidth = getWidth + totalWidth;
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="1920px" height="1080px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 1080" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Route">
 <path id="P1" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M313.44-124.783L443.635,5.412"/>
 
 <path id="P2" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M443.635,5.412L550.41,112.187"/>
 <path id="P3" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M550.412,112.188l23.482,23.481"/>
 <path id="P4" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M573.892,135.67l38.689,38.688"/>
 <path id="P5" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M612.584,174.36h34.893"/>
 <path id="P6" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M647.473,174.36h25.833"/>
 <path id="P7" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M673.306,174.36h24.928"/>
 <path id="P8" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M698.233,174.36h26.257"/>
 <path id="P9" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M724.49,174.36h31.206"/>
 <path id="P10" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M755.697,174.36h42.438"/>
 <path id="P11" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M798.135,174.36v42.979"/>
 <path id="P12" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M798.135,217.336v30.479"/>
 <path id="P13" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M798.135,247.819v63.196"/>
 <path id="P14" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M798.135,311.015v90.118"/>
 <path id="P15" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M798.135,401.133v97.602"/>
 <path id="P16" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M798.135,498.734v49.254"/>
 <path id="P17" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M798.135,547.988l-52.483,52.483"/>
 <path id="P18" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M745.646,600.472l-52.483,52.479"/>
 <path id="P19" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M693.162,652.949H652.24"/>
 <path id="P20" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M652.24,652.949h-50.372"/>
 <path id="P21" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M601.867,652.949h-36.341"/>
 <path id="P22" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M565.527,652.949h-35.425"/>
 <path id="P23" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M533.997,652.949h-40.188"/>
 <path id="P24" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M493.805,652.949h-68.578"/>
 <path id="P25" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M425.227,652.949v-40.56"/>
 <path id="P26" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M425.227,612.392v-50.037"/>
 <path id="P27" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M425.227,562.354v-81.003"/>
 <path id="P28" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M425.227,481.35h-19.677"/>
 <path id="P29" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M405.552,481.35h-26.26"/>
 <path id="P30" fill="none" stroke="#2B2A29" d="M379.293,481.35h-32.354"/>
</g>
<g id="Route">
 <path id="P1_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,60.169v32.615"/>
 <path id="P2_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,92.784v26.682"/>
 <path id="P3_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,119.466v54.895"/>
 <path id="P4_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,174.36v35.871"/>
 <path id="P5_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,210.231v40.771"/>
 <path id="P6_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,251.001v43.005"/>
 <path id="P7_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,294.004v19.929"/>
 <path id="P8_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,313.936v39.021"/>
 <path id="P9_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,352.953v30.873"/>
 <path id="P10_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,383.825v38.911"/>
 <path id="P11_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.697,422.74l0.002,30.627"/>
 <path id="P12_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.698,453.365v25.745"/>
 <path id="P13_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M755.698,479.114l-29.396,29.396"/>
 <path id="P14_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M726.303,508.511l-22.48,22.477"/>
 <path id="P15_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M703.822,530.988l-37.764,37.77"/>
 <path id="P16_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M666.06,568.75l-20.278,20.276"/>
 <path id="P17_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M645.781,589.031l-21.888,21.894"/>
 <path id="P18_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M623.893,610.922l-18.252,18.248"/>
 <path id="P19_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M605.641,629.17l-19.089,19.093"/>
 <path id="P20_1_" fill="none" stroke="#E21B6C" d="M586.552,648.263l-14.313,14.313"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally do not need jquery or d3 for this but since you asked I'll do it with d3.

First get the start and end points from your path segments and push them into an array, that should be the points you can use for your curve:

```
 var curvePoints = [];
var cardinal = d3.svg.line().interpolate("cardinal");//d3v3!
d3.selectAll("#Route path").each(function(d,i){
    var point1;
    var point2 = this.getPointAtLength(this.getTotalLength());
    !i ? (point1 = this.getPointAtLength(0), curvePoints.push([point1.x,point1.y])) : void(0);
    curvePoints.push([point2.x,point2.y]);
});
```

`cardinal(curvePoints)` will give you the "d" attribute path string you want.

On your click handler hide the #Route g, and show a new path with  cardinal(curvePoints) as its d attribute.

PS:

- In the example you have provided, the line is still composed many line segments. Possibly the "stroke-linejoin" is tricking you to think that it is a single curve.
- They are selecting all these paths and transitioning them.
- Since you asked in your original question, how to translate them into a curve, I will do it with a single curve. This is also faster because you are not updating ~30 nodes but a single node.
- [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/wkorL072/60/) is the concept. It will warp between line confirmation and a curve one. Behind the curve, there are the original path segments.

Comment: I didn't check it on the console. Let me try just a sec.

Comment: Thank you @ibowankenobi

i have applied all your code its working but not give me proper path
and i have multiple routs so may be its not working with this code

Comment: No, I had points instead of curvedPoints. I just tried it on your g element, it works now.

Comment: Cool its working, but still need your help i want straight line with animation on same place. its that possible??

Comment: By animation what exactly do you mean? Do you want to hide the original line segments and show the curve? Or do you want to animate the curve starting with 0 length until it is full length?

Comment: i want to create something like this https://www.findproperly.co.uk/tube-map.php#.Wtr0qS5uaUn Please refer this link and click on lines

Comment: check my updated answer. I guess this answers your original question completely.

Comment: Wow, Its exactly what i want Thank you so much SIR.